# Further options to modify the x-axis in a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx} %kleinere Textgröße

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@math@if@@doif{%
    \pgfmathparse{\tikz@math@if@condition}%
    \ifpgfmathfloatparseactive%                 <--- Notice this
    \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%   <--- Notice this
    \fi%                                        <--- Notice this
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\relax%
    \else%
        \expandafter\tikz@math\expandafter{\tikz@math@if@trueaction}%
    \fi%
    \tikz@math@parse%
}
\def\tikz@math@if@@doifelse{%
    \pgfmathparse{\tikz@math@if@condition}%
    \let\tikz@math@if@falseaction=\tikz@math@collected%
    \message{^^JCheck this: \pgfmathresult^^J}% <--- Notice this
    \ifpgfmathfloatparseactive%                 <--- Notice this
        \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%   <--- Notice this
    \fi%                                        <--- Notice this
    \message{^^JCheck again: \pgfmathresult^^J}%<--- Notice this
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\relax%
    \expandafter\tikz@math\expandafter{\tikz@math@if@falseaction}%
    \else%
        \expandafter\tikz@math\expandafter{\tikz@math@if@trueaction}%
    \fi%
    \tikz@math@parse%
}

\tikzmath                    
{
  function testfunction(\x) 
  {
    if (0 <= \x && \x <= sqrt(3)/24) then
    {
        return (0.002 * 24 * \x / sqrt(3));
    }
    else 
    {
    if (sqrt(3)/24 <= \x && \x <= sqrt(3) / 12) then
    {
       return (0.002 * 24 * (sqrt(3)/12 - \x) / sqrt(3));
    }
    else 
    {
        return (0.002 * 24 * (\x - sqrt(3)/12));
    };  
   };
  };
\a = testfunction(0);
\b = testfunction(2*0.07217);
\c = testfunction(4*0.07217);
}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
          [
        ,width=7cm
       ,xtick=    {0,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.14433756729,0.16867512,0.17867512,0.18867512,0.19867512,0.20867512,0.21867512,0.22867512,0.23867512,0.24867512,0.25867512}
    ,xticklabels={\,,\scalebox{.4}{$d_m$}, \,, \,, \,,\,,\,,\,,\,,\scalebox{.4}{$d_{r+1}$},\scalebox{.4}{$d_r$}, \scalebox{.4}{$d_{r-1}$},\,,\,,\,,\,,\,,\,,\,,\scalebox{.4}{$d_{1}$},\scalebox{.4}{$d_{0}$}}
        ]               
    \addplot[blue, domain = 0:sqrt(3)/6]{testfunction(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: My output]

The modification options I'd like to have are something like this:

[image: Goal]

[Reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.08775)

I'd like to add braces between two points to highlight certain distances and give further informations. Additionally, I want the labelling `$d_k$` of each mark to be above the x-axis as in the second picture.

I looked through the pgfplot manual but still haven't found what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you turn your snippet into a [complete example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? If it was only a case of adding `\usepackage{pgfplots}` it wouldn't be so bad, but the definition of `testfunction` is missing as well.

Comment: ... and then remove `![enter image description here][1]][1]` after `7cm`, please. BTW, by adding `xticklabel style={above}` you'll have the labels inside.

Comment: Corrected post so far, the first part of my code is to fix a bug occurring using the if statements. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to do something like the following? Please have a look at the comments in the code for more details.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        calc,
        math,
    }
    % use this `compat' level or higher to use the "advanced" features for
    % setting the axis labels
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
    \makeatletter
        \def\tikz@math@if@@doif{%
            \pgfmathparse{\tikz@math@if@condition}%
            \ifpgfmathfloatparseactive%                 <--- Notice this
            \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%       <--- Notice this
            \fi%                                        <--- Notice this
            \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\relax%
            \else%
                \expandafter\tikz@math\expandafter{\tikz@math@if@trueaction}%
            \fi%
            \tikz@math@parse%
        }
        \def\tikz@math@if@@doifelse{%
            \pgfmathparse{\tikz@math@if@condition}%
            \let\tikz@math@if@falseaction=\tikz@math@collected%
            \message{^^JCheck this: \pgfmathresult^^J}% <--- Notice this
            \ifpgfmathfloatparseactive%                 <--- Notice this
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%   <--- Notice this
            \fi%                                        <--- Notice this
            \message{^^JCheck again: \pgfmathresult^^J}%<--- Notice this
            \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\relax%
            \expandafter\tikz@math\expandafter{\tikz@math@if@falseaction}%
            \else%
                \expandafter\tikz@math\expandafter{\tikz@math@if@trueaction}%
            \fi%
            \tikz@math@parse%
        }
    \makeatletter

    \tikzmath{
        function testfunction(\x){
            if (0 <= \x && \x <= sqrt(3)/24) then {
                return (0.002 * 24 * \x / sqrt(3));
            } else {
                if (sqrt(3)/24 <= \x && \x <= sqrt(3) / 12) then {
                    return (0.002 * 24 * (sqrt(3)/12 - \x) / sqrt(3));
                } else {
                    return (0.002 * 24 * (\x - sqrt(3)/12));
                };
            };
        };
        \a = testfunction(0);
        \b = testfunction(2*0.07217);
        \c = testfunction(4*0.07217);
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=7cm,
        xtick={
            0,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11,0.12,
            0.14433756729,0.16867512,0.17867512,0.18867512,0.19867512,
            0.20867512,0.21867512,0.22867512,0.23867512,0.24867512,0.25867512
        },
        xticklabels={
            ,\scalebox{.4}{$d_m$},,,,,,,,\scalebox{.4}{$d_{r+1}$},
            \scalebox{.4}{$d_r$},\scalebox{.4}{$d_{r-1}$},,,,,,,,
            \scalebox{.4}{$d_{1}$},\scalebox{.4}{$d_{0}$}
        },
        xticklabel style={
            % move the ticklabels to the inside of the plot ...
            above,
            yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length},
            % ... and give each of them a name
            name=tickLabel-\ticknum,
        },
        % set the `ylabel'
        ylabel={$\varphi(t)$},
        % don't draw any `yticklabels'
        yticklabels={},
        % don't draw the scaling factor
        scaled ticks=false,
        % don't clip TikZ coordinates
        clip mode=individual,
    ]
        \addplot [blue,domain=0:sqrt(3)/6] {testfunction(x)};

        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,...,20} {
            % create another set of coordinates that is shifted below the
            % axis line (this is done by the "3pt")
            \coordinate (TickLabel-#1)
                at (tickLabel-#1 |- {xticklabel cs:0,3pt});

%            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
%            % for debugging purposes only
%            \node [node font=\tiny,red] at (TickLabel-#1) {#1};
%            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        }

        % draw horizontal arrows below the axis
        \begin{scope}[
            stealth-stealth,
        ]
            \draw (TickLabel-0)  -- coordinate (rho half) (TickLabel-1);
            \draw (TickLabel-7)  -- coordinate (cM-1)     (TickLabel-9);
            \draw (TickLabel-9)  -- coordinate (square)   (TickLabel-11);
            \draw (TickLabel-11) -- coordinate (cM-2)     (TickLabel-13);
            \draw (TickLabel-18) --                       (TickLabel-20);
        \end{scope}


        % draw dots
        \node at ($ (TickLabel-1)!0.5!(TickLabel-7) $)      {$\cdots$};
        \node at ($ (TickLabel-13)!0.5!(TickLabel-18) $)    {$\cdots$};

        % draw labels
        \begin{scope}[
            every node/.append style={
                node font=\scriptsize,
                yshift=-5ex,
            },
        ]
            \node (label rho half) at (rho half)
                {$\frac{\rho}{2}$};
            \node [xshift=-6ex] (label cM-1) at (cM-1)
                {$\frac{c_2}{\sqrt{M}}$};
            \node (label square) at (square)
                {$2 c_1 \sqrt{\frac{\log(M)}{M}}$};
            \node [xshift=6ex]  (label cM-2) at (cM-2)
                {$\frac{c_2}{\sqrt{M}}$};
        \end{scope}

        % draw arrows between labels
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {
            rho half,
            cM-1,
            square,
            cM-2%
        } {
            \edef\temp{\noexpand%
                \draw [->] (label \i) -- ([yshift=-2pt]\i);
            }\temp
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Great, yeah I want to adapt something like this for other graphics, too. Thanks a lot! Btw should I add the reference of the second picture?

Comment: As you like ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow Kind colleague you absolutely must not thank me. It is objective that you are very good at your job.